# Is there a data structure for DAGs that supports efficient edits?

Tags: data-structures, graph, cycle, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm looking for a data structure that will store any DAG, but can efficiently (i.e., sub-linearly in the number of edges/vertices) detect if adding an edge would create a cycle (and thus prevent you from breaking the acyclic invariant). Does anyone know of such a thing?

Thanks!

Comment: This paper, [Faster Algorithms for Incremental Topological
Ordering](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~sssix/papers/dto-conf.pdf), claims an **amortized** O(m^1/2) per arc addition.  Not sure if that's good enough, or if a worst-case bound is possible.  I haven't read beyond the introduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could maintain a datastructure about the graph's **[transitive closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure)**. Then checking whether adding an edge causes cycles is done in constant time; if you want to add edge (i,j), check if there is already a path from j to i. However, updating the datastructure could be more costly in general (see e.g. [La Poutré and van Leeuwen](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-19422-3_9)).